# Dynamic precompile assets on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, erb, sprockets

We use a **css.scss.erb** file in our code. This file access to de models an iterate over a each loop to create a css file. Sometimes we need to redo the file (when the model change).

```
**stylesheets/utils/_comunicaciones.css.scss.erb**

   <%Producto.all.each do |img| %>
    <%unless img.portada.blank?%>
    ##{$id}--<%=img.id%> {

        &:before {
            background: url('<%= img.portada.url(:icon_lands) %>');

            background-position: $bg-position;
            background-size: $bg-size;
            background-repeat: $bg-repeat;
        }
    }
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

We put a config.assets.precompile line in config/initializers/assets.rb for this insue.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( stylesheets/utils/_comunicaciones.css.scss.erb )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( '*.css.scss.erb' )
```

To make it work in development mode, we foce the change of the file when the model changes.

```
class  ProductoImagen < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save  :precompilar
belongs_to :producto

    def precompilar
  fichero =  File.read('app/assets/stylesheets/utils/_comunicaciones.css.scss.erb').split('/* #=cambios')[0].to_s + '/*' + " #=cambios " + Time.now.to_s + '*/'
  File.open('app/assets/stylesheets/utils/_comunicaciones.css.scss.erb','w') {|f| f.write(fichero)}
  #Rails.application.load_tasks
  #Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
end
```

What should I do to make the file change in production mode?
How can I do to re-precompile a file and next reload de application?

Comment: Assets that are pre-compiled should stay as they are; pre-compiled (not re-compiled). It's not a good idea (nor a good practice) to force an asset compilation and runtime due to possible inconsistencies (read while writing). You should probably place them within the view, which are compiled and served at runtime. You can also use the [Rails cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

Comment: Ok, only re-compiled when de administration work. in a few times. thanks for your view of the problem. But it's posible to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if the assets pipeline can be accessed runtime. You may want to create a new controller to serve these files, and pre-compile them on demmand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to precompile something you want. Just embed styles in your html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- some static styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/application.css">

    <!-- dynamic styles -->
    <style>
        <%Producto.all.each do |img| %>
            ##{$id}--<%=img.id%> {
                background: url('<%= img.portada.url(:icon_lands) %>');
                background-position: $bg-position;
                background-size: $bg-size;
                background-repeat: $bg-repeat;
            }
        }
        <%end%>
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <!-- some html -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, it will be better to paste this code in partial or helper.

Comment: Yes I know this option. But I think is better put code and styles separated.